# VB .NET Microsoft.Owin.Hosting WebApp.Start gives nullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, exception, owin, nullreferenceexception

Here's my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Const url As String = "http://localhost:9001"
        
        Using WebApp.Start(url)
            Console.WriteLine("Server started at:" & url)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

The exception occurs

[image: As the error shows I am getting a null reference exception here don't know why]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Best not to include error info as an image—it's not searchable for others to find. Best to include it as text.

Comment: The call itself looks fine (`Start` is a `Shared` function so it doesn't require an instance, and `url` is trivially non-null), so I would guess that you are missing something else that OWIN requires.

Comment: Hi @Craig I don't know what I am doing wrong here because if I follow this link: http://www.codedigest.com/posts/2/creating-our-first-owin-based-application
I think I am doing fine converting my code to VB but I still get an error. But the C# code works fine as can be seen in this repo: https://github.com/RoccoSen/OwinToWebAPI.git I think I am doing something wrong with respect to VB

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax for the `Using` statement is wrong. It is supposed to be similar to a variable declaration:

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Const url As String = "http://localhost:9001"
        
        Using wa As New WebApp
            wa.Start(url)
            Console.WriteLine("Server started at:" & url)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

More information is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.Using)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.0)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I get compile time errors from this solution: 'Using' operand of type 'WebApp' must implement 'System.IDisposable'. and the second error is that: Overload resolution failed because no 'New' is accessible.

Comment: This might be pointing in the right direction, but it's not the right syntax for this case.  As I noted in my comment on the question, `WebApp.Start` is a `Shared` routine which returns an object that implements `IDisposable`.